# Foreign Key in Rest API design

Tags: rest

Say there are a USER table and a GROUP table in a relational database.  As a user can be in many groups and a group can have many users it is Many-to-Many relationship between User and Group.

Now for **GET /api/user/userid**, should the group field be like

Option 1: **[groupid1, groupid2,...]**

Option 2: **[{id: groupid1, name: groupname,..}, {id: groupid2, name: groupdname,....}]**

Option 3: **A separate endpoint should be used for group field like GET /api/usergroups/userid**

I feel like Option 2 makes more sense for the consumers of the API. But i have seen some big names simply use Option 1. What is your opinion?

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage it is duplicate. Thanks!